# Bug in UITableViewController in Storyboard

Tags: objective-c, storyboard, uitableview

I'm creating a UITableViewController to list names of people and a star next to their name to indicating favorite people like so

[image: one of many cells]

The stars light up when touched, indicting a favorite, the row number of that cell goes into an NSMutableArray which is called in this method.

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

When I tap a cell and add the index to the array, everything works, until I scroll down, and more stars are filled. They are in random, I believe, a few popup every time I scroll up then down, and look like this, faded stars...

[image: faded star]

This is the full star

[image: full star]

Somehow the stars that shouldn't be filled are faded.

I cannot pin point where the stars are getting switched to on. The log only shows setting the star to on when I scroll to the particular cell.

My problem is that stars are switched on when they should not be, my array is good, I've checked that multiple times, it has to be the UITableView.

This is my code,

I only have two images of that star, one filled and one empty, and the

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    //    NSLog(@"%i",[[cell.contentView subviews] count]);
    //    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[cell.contentView subviews]];
    [tableView reloadData];
    UIImageView *star = cell.star;
    NSLog(@"Star Tag: %i",star.tag);

    if (star.tag == kStarEmpty) {
        [[Global sharedGlobal].favTeachers addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",cell.identifierTag]];
        NSLog(@"Added: %i",cell.identifierTag);
     //   NSLog(@"setting star image: 1");
        [star setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"]];
        [star setTag:kStarFilled];
    } else if (star.tag == kStarFilled) {
        [[Global sharedGlobal].favTeachers removeObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",cell.identifierTag]];
        NSLog(@"Removed: %i",cell.identifierTag);
      //      NSLog(@"setting star image: 2");
        [star setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star_empty.png"]];
        [star setTag:kStarEmpty];
    }

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *teacher = [[Global sharedGlobal].teachers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[CustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    UIImageView *starView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    starView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_empty.png"];
    starView.frame = CGRectMake(720, 2, 29, 29); //748,22
    [starView setTag:kStarEmpty];
    cell.star = starView;
    [cell addSubview:starView];

    cell.identifierTag = indexPath.row;

    NSLog(@"This cell's identifier tag: %i",cell.identifierTag);

    cell.textLabel.text = [[Global sharedGlobal].teachers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    for (int i = 0; i < [[Global sharedGlobal].favTeachers count]; i++) {
        int favTeacherTag = [[[Global sharedGlobal].favTeachers objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        NSLog(@"%i",i);
        NSLog(@"Fav Teacher Tag: %i",favTeacherTag);
        if (cell.identifierTag == favTeacherTag) {
            NSLog(@"found fav teacher: %i",cell.identifierTag);
            NSLog(@"------------------------------------------");
    //        NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[cell.contentView subviews]];

            NSLog(@"setting star image");
            [starView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"]];
            NSLog(@"Previous star tag: %i",starView.tag);
            [starView setTag:kStarFilled];
            break;
        }

        NSLog(@"--------------------------------");
    }

    return cell;
}
```

EXTRA INFO:

- I have a custom class for the cells, which adds the `cell.identifierTag` as an `int`.
- I am using Storyboard
- I use static cells in Storyboard

Thank you! If you need any more information please comment and ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure to set the `UIImage` to `nil` in the **else** block here:

```
if (cell.identifierTag == favTeacherTag) {
    //your existing code
} else {
    [starView setImage:nil];
};
```

This is because the cells are reused, and you may be getting a cell that had previously had the star image added.

Answer (score 1):

call [tableView reloadData] at end of (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method

Answer (score 0):

After two days of this I finally figured it out. :D

I added this code, because I was using the same UIImageView sometimes and kept adding image views every time this `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` was called.

```
UIImageView *starView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

if (cell.star == nil) {
    starView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star_empty.png"];
    starView.frame = CGRectMake(720, 2, 29, 29); //748,22
    [starView setTag:kStarEmpty];
    cell.star = starView;

    [cell addSubview:starView];
} else if (cell.star != nil) {
    starView = cell.star;
}
```